# CSS scrolling on both html element and fixed element with min-width

Tags: css, position, fixed

Try the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="min-width:600px; overflow:auto;">
        <body style="background:grey; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
                <div style="text-align:right;">
                     this is some text
                </div>
            <div id="footer" style="
                    background:yellow;
                    position:fixed;
                    height: 100px;
                    width:100%;
                    min-width: 600px;
                    text-align:right;
                    bottom:0px;
                    ">
                    footer text
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

So when I make the width of the browser window less than 600px, a horizontal scroll bar appears at the bottom of the window as expected.  When I scroll to the right, the phrase "this is some text" scrolls into view, which is great.  However, the phrase "footer text" does not scroll into view, which is the problem.

How do I get both the "footer text" and "this is some text" to scroll into view as I drag the window scroll bar to the right? THe yellow footer must always appear at the bottom of the website.

I would prefer a clean CSS solution to this.  I will accept a javascript solution if absolutely necessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because for `fixed` elements the containing block is not en element but the viewport (cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)

You should try the method described here which use `absolute` positionning: http://alistapart.com/article/footers

OP says:
Thanks. I used jquery by doing `$(window).scroll(function(){$('#footer').css('left', parseInt(-1*$(window).scrollLeft();)+'px');});` I guess that was easy enough

Comment: I looked in all the examples of the alistapart.com website.  When i shrink the window to say 30px by 30px, the footer is no longer in view.  I have to vertically scroll to the bottom to see the footer.  How do I make the footer always visible at the bottom of the window instead of bottom of the web page?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use JavaScript to achieve the exact behaviour.

Comment: Thanks.  I used jquery by doing `$(window).scroll(function(){$('#footer').css('left', parseInt(-1*$(window).scrollLeft();)+'px');});`  I guess that was easy enough

Answer (score 0):

Take out the min-width on your second div. That will allow the footer text to always show no matter what the size of the viewport.

Comment: i needed to add the min-width because i plan to have A LOT of floating elements inside the footer.  The elements need to take up at least 600px.   if the footer gets smaller than 600px, then everything floats out of position.